# sqlite error in android

Tags: android

I am getting the value from webservice. I am storing in sqlite. While storing in sqlite, I am getting an error. even I replaced single quote with "\'". Which characters are not supported in sqlite?

My error is:

```
03-26 13:22:22.478: WARN/System.err(311): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error:
```

My insert statement is:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TableName
                     +"("+fieldname+")"
                     +" VALUES ('"+(homevalue)+"');");
```

Can anybody tell what to do or give an example?

Comment: Can you print the string "INSERT INTO "+TableName +"("+fieldname+")" +" VALUES ('"+(homevalue)+"');"

Answer (score 1):

there is a name which is like "name's" i.e this single quote is problem

Answer (score 0):

I am just a beginner, 
but i think you should write it like this:

```
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(" + feildName + ") VALUES ('" + homeValue + "');"
```

you put () around the homeValue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your string TableName, fieldname  or homevalue contains some quotation. print out the query first and see.